# Touching certain pins (grounding body capacitance) causing pcb to work

Tags: voltage, power, capacitor, pcb, current

I'm using a siren generator circuit to generate signal and trace it using an amplification circuit.

This circuit is working and tested before but this time I'm not getting good sound on the amplifier unless I touch pin number 3 or 7 of IC2 (555).

I know my body has capacitance and resistance (wiki says 100 pF and 1.5 kOhm) which explains why in such cases people ground a 100 pF cap.

Yet that didn't solve my problem, an open circuit of 1000 uF seemed to boost the output a lot but not quite as much as my physical touch to the pin does.

Also it's the same problem across 5 boards, so I doubt it's soldering problem

Here is the schematic:

[image]

Here is the schematic for the 555:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- the 100pF  model is only for the arc of a finger tip with ESD.
- I can get 1000 pF easily with my fingers pressing on an LCR meter.

In any case your layour probably lacks basic EMI controls for ground plane, excessive long inductive jumpers to the switch and perhaps missing decoupling caps on Vcc to Vdd.

- try these methods

  - add decoupling cap on Vcc (.1uF ) Pin 4 & 1 for each IC and >=10uF
  - twist all long wires (signal, switched power and ground return)

If your wiring layout looked anything like the logic diagram , it would never work due to inductive effects crosstalk glitches.

Show photo's or study how to layout a breadboard.

Comment: okay thanks for commenting nevertheless nothing you said worked, tried 0.1uf and 47uf not much better, same goes for decoupling, yeah could be an inductive problem and i'm probably amature at this but the thing is, if something changes when i touch it then i can technically compensate with that effect using electronics which is why i've this thread

Comment: your finger can inject many volts of 50Hz AC hum into high impedances. but without any photo, scope readings or details on layout, I cant help you even though I could figure out what's wrong